# Zuul request headers not forwarded

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-zuul

I have an application that uses Zuul and is hosted in a Kubernetes Cluster on AWS. It would appear that Zuul is not forwarding headers from the request to the destination, so I m having to do this:

```
private void copyRequestHeaders() {
    RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();
    Enumeration<String> headerNames = context.getRequest().getHeaderNames();
    while(headerNames.hasMoreElements()) {
       String headerName = headerNames.nextElement();
       context.addZuulRequestHeader(headerName, context.getRequest().getHeader(headerName));
    }
}
```

I'm guessing that I shouldn't have to do this and that I'm missing a configuration option somewhere or something like that. Can anyone shed any light on this. Interestingly the application works fine in my local development environment.

I'd also like to know the purpose of the ZuulRequestHeader and ZuulResponseHeadera and how they differ from standard request and response headers. Are they wrappers perhaps?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Try adding the `sensitiveHeaders` in your configuration.

```
zuul:
    routes:
        sample:
            sensitiveHeaders:
            path: /sample
```

Removing any values on `sensitiveHeaders` means that all headers passed on your Zuul Gateway will be passed deep within the microservices.

For more information, refer to this [documentation](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi__router_and_filter_zuul.html#_cookies_and_sensitive_headers).

Answer (score 3):

By default, Zuul API Gateway will not let sensitive information to be forwarded to downstream Microservices.
The default value for this property is

```
zuul.sensitiveHeaders: Cookie,Set-Cookie,Authorization
```

we can override this value to allow certain headers by

```
zuul.sensitiveHeaders: Cookie,Set-Cookie
```

And to allow all the headers we can keep it blank

```
zuul.sensitiveHeaders:
```